# Connecting Github actions to my salesforce

Tags: ci, github, cicd

i am starting to learn CI/CD and i want to create Github actions for my salesforce project.
for when I need the SFDX URL, the format is this ( after executing force:force:org:display -u ORG-ALIAS --verbose) :
force://::@
And in the result there is no client secret ( as salesforce mentions in their docs, it not included to prevent security breaches). So i searched in managed apps, and i don't have one for github. should i make a connected apps for github so i can get the client secret ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a Connected App for GitHub. The `sfdx` CLI has a built-in Connected App, which is used with the SFDX URL authorization you already have. You'll store your SFDX Auth URL in the secrets for your GitHub repo and ingest it into `sfdx` in your Actions run; no other authentication is required to access the org.

Comment: Oh okay, but when running sfdx force:org:display command to get my orgs info, it does return the Sfdx auth URL as this format , but not the form needed in the documentation for the salesforce CLI, which it should be : force://<refreshToken>@<instanceUrl> or force://<clientId>:<clientSecret>:<refreshToken>@<instanceUrl> , when executing the command the url provided to me : force://PlatformCLI::XXXXXX@org-org-org-dev-ed.my.s (example). any help ??

Comment: The output of SFDX should be fine.

Comment: exactly, i'v seen it work for others giving the exact output but my ouptut  goes like this : force://PlatformCLI::XXXX@oussama-bht-8-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com

Comment: @OussamaBoumhaout Please stop posting your auth URL. You are providing the Internet at large access to your org. You should revoke active OAuth sessions in your org.  I don't see why you're concerned about this unless it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a [private key](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_key_and_cert.htm) and put it in repo secrets, then follow my gists for complete github action yaml:

[Apex unit tests](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/561fdbf59f30c00f2ed73145d527ddcf)

[Apex prettier](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/701ea16c08abf7fa743a6162539d94e9)

[Apex PMD](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/76d5930c664d8548b1329c4517dfb250)

[Aura and LWC lint](https://gist.github.com/sjurgis/16cb5e1e1dc4d68ad3cf2151d848c7a3)